# When to use plural of "archipelago"

Tags: meaning

The definition of *archipelago* by Oxford Dictionary is the following:

> an extensive group of islands

The definition of *archipelago* given by Cambridge Dictionary is instead the following one:

> a group of small islands or an area of sea in which there are many small islands

I can conclude that, by both definitions, *archipelago* itself always means plural.

Both dictionaries give us the plural of the word as well, which are *archipelagos* and *archipelagoes*.

When should we use *archipelagos* or *archipelagoes* which means the plural of an extensive group of islands?

Comment: I think this is general reference. Just because *archipelago* has two valid spellings doesn't make this any different to asking when you should say *groups* as opposed to *group*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Archipelago* is a singular noun as the group of islands is viewed as a collective whole. *Archipelagos* or *archipelagoes* is the plural noun referring to more than one group of islands.

Comment: Indonesian archipelago & Philippines archipelago or I can say Indonesian and Philippines archipelagoes, then.

Answer (score 10):

Your two dictionaries say that an archipelago is **an** extensive group of islands or **a** group of small islands. As Jasper Loy says, collective nouns are singular by definition: they refer to **a** group of things.

Here's another example of plural use: *There are three archipelagos off the north and north-west coasts of Scotland: the Orkney Islands, the Shetland Isles and the Western Isles (or Outer Hebrides)*.